# Trying to get a list of all the TR rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for any ignorance I have - my Javascript is not great.

Anyway, I have this in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableRows = document.getElementbyId("inventorytable").childNodes;

alert(tableRows)
</script>
```

As far as I know, it should grab the children of the table with the id of "inventorytable", correct?

Trying to eventually move down the tree of the DOM to the children of the children of the table (i.e. the TDs) and adding strings dependent on where in the table they're located. But for right now just trying to select the table's children and alerting them out.

I've added this code, still no alert:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function inventorytable() {
var tableRows = document.getElementbyId("inventorytable").rows;

alert(tableRows.length);
};
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var tableRows = document.getElementbyId("inventorytable").rows;
alert(tableRows.length);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows

Comment: I tried that, still no alert popping up - could it have something to do with the fact that I put it in my header?

Comment: Take a look at @gryzzly's answer (+1).

Comment: getElementById, not getElementbyId

Answer (score 1):

You should do either of two things:

1. put this code before closing `</body>` tag
2. wrap this with a function and attach that function as event handler to DOMReady or window load event.

The reason for this is that when your code is executed (when it's being read from within a script tag in the head) the DOM (the tree of HTML elements) is not yet read.

The second option could look like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  //your code here
  var tableRows = document.getElementbyId("inventorytable").childNodes;
  alert(tableRows);
};
```

DOMReady event is not supported cross-browserly, so there is a library that you can use to attach logic to that event – http://code.google.com/p/domready/

I suggest you read the explanation here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/, and if you are going to use jQuery, then you'd do it like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  // your code here…
  // instead of writing `document.getElementbyId("inventorytable").childNodes;`
  // you could do
  var tableRows = $('#inventorytable').find('tr');
  alert( tableRows );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var tableRows = document.getElementById("inventorytable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Note that `tbody` is require to work on **IE** browsers. Then loop these elements and `alert` them

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    window.alert(tableRows[i].tagName); // Or whatever...
}
```

This is a **cross-browser** technique, may work everywhere :)

Comment: It's cross-browser ? It seems to be some of those IE-only properties. Gonna try it out.

Comment: :) Yes, and it's a only true way to get TBODY of TABLE. MDN:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.tBodies MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537490%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: "only" ? I've always used the way I posted. Well, thank you for the tip, this is new to me!

Comment: About your way: what if table contains child tables? You sure that your way return proper TBODY?

Comment: Doesnt `getElementesByTagName` returns the straight after tag? So in my example even if table has other tables inside, it will return the `tbody` just after the parent object, am I right ?